# Box-shadow not looks same for both safari and chrome

Tags: css, shadow, box-shadow

I have given box shadow effect for a DIV. But the same code looks darker in safari and thinner in chrome. The shadow not appear in left and top for chrome browser.

```
.div_wrapper {
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px -6px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px -6px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px -6px black;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Your box shadow rules should be ordered in reverse.

Comment: If you share your screen

Comment: Instead of using `black` you can use `rgba()`. Example: `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)`. You can change the value `0.30` to something higher or lower. E.g. `0.30` lighter then `0.90`.

Comment: This is the layout for box shadow effect: looks different in chrome.

         https://jsfiddle.net/jayabharathi/3je7qwqg/1/

Answer (score 1):

It's normal. Some CSS properties will behave differently due to the difference of representation mechanism of diffierent browsers.

In addition, you can also [load different CSS file for different browsers](http://www.ampercent.com/load-separate-css-for-different-browsers/4750/).